# C# - Calling a class I created in another class

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes in my program: Program, Board, and Square.
In program I'm creating a new board:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Board b = new Board();
    }
}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to call the Board I created here in my Square class.
Anyone have an Idea how to do this? (not to create a new Board in the Square class).
Edit:
I'm trying to create a simple mine-sweeper game.
In the Board class I have a two-dimensional array of Squars. then I creat in each part of the square array a new Square. Then the board is creating mines with the "AddMine" function in the Square class. I have deleted the way the board is choosing which square to set to a mine.

```
class Board
{
    public Square[,] board;
    public int n;

    public Board()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the nuber of rows on column(int): ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        board = new Square[n, n];
        mines = (n * n) / 6;
        for (int row = 0; row < board.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < board.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                board[row, col] = new Square(row, col);
            }
        }
        board[row, col].AddMine();
    }
}
```

In the Square class, at first it is setting is val to 0. After that when I'm calling The "AddMine" function from board, I need to add one to the val of each Square nearby the square who is set to mine.

```
class Square
{
    public Board b;
    private int row, col;
    public int val;
    private bool open;
    public Square(int row, int col)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        open = false;
        val = 0;

    }
    public void AddMine()
    {
        #region set this to bomb (-9), nearby squars ++
        val = -9;
        b.board[row, (col + 1)].val++;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The real question is how do I call the board array in the Board class in the Square class? because this way is not working, I get a 'System.NullReferenceException' error, I know it is because b is set to 'null', but I don't know to what to do so it will be able to see the Board from Main in Programe class.
All the answers I found in the internet is or to set a new Board, or to set a prorame class in the squarwe class, but because I'm setting a new board in a static function, it is not working.
Thanks to anyone for helping and I hope now the question is clearer.

Comment: I don't see a "Board I created here in my Square class." I only see a Program class. There are different ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Generally speaking... pass it in on a method parameter.

Comment: where is the code for Square class ? You can create `Static` methods if you don't want instance to be created

Comment: When you create an instance of the `Square` class, pass it this instance of `Board` via a method or property. Or vice versa. If a `Board` has 64 `Square`s, it should probably create them itself.

Comment: ^^ or use a separate board builder class

Comment: Better read some docs about c# before asking unclear questions..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many have said you need to pass the reference to the board into the Square.  You almost have it in your example, you just don't actually pass the board in.

Here's what your square class should look like.

```
class Square
{
    public Board b;
    private int row, col;
    public int val;
    private bool open;
    public Square(Board board, int row, int col)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        open = false;
        val = 0;
        **b = board;**    
    }
    public void AddMine()
    {
        #region set this to bomb (-9), nearby squars ++
        val = -9;
        b.board[row, (col + 1)].val++;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

You received the null reference exception because you never actually set the board object so it was null when you tried to use it.

Then to edit your board example, this is how you would add the new squares.

```
class Board
{
    public Square[,] board;
    public int n;

    public Board()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the nuber of rows on column(int): ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        board = new Square[n, n];
        mines = (n * n) / 6;
        for (int row = 0; row < board.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < board.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                board[row, col] = new Square(this, row, col);
            }
        }
        board[row, col].AddMine();
    }
}
```

The "this" keywoard is just a reference to the calling object.

That should solve your problem, but I should note this is not usually considered the best practice.  It seems your heading in the direction of tightly coupling your classes which can easily lead to smelly and unmaintainable code.  You should look into tightly coupled vs loosely coupled code.  A quick google search turned up this article
[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yusufkaratoprak/difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling/](http://Difference%20Between%20Loose%20Coupling%20and%20Tight%20Coupling)

Comment: When I'm trying to write "b = board; " in the Square class as you suggested, I get an error that "The name 'board' does not exist in the current context" What to do? and anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you remember to add it to the parameters in the constructor?

Comment: public Square(Board board, int row, int col)

Comment: I dont know why, but when I rewrite what you suggested and now it is working. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Using passing object reference as a parameter in method you can achieve your desire output. Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Board d=new Board();
       Square s=new Square();
       s.m1(d);
    }
}

class Board
{
   int x=10;
}

class Square
{
    public void m1(Board a)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(a.x);
    }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I need to have access to the array from the whole class, not just in one function (please see my adit).